# Vagrant up "error while executing VBoxManage"

Tags: console, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm running into an issue when trying to initialize Vagrant. Got a folder set up with a Vagrantfile along with VirtualBox and Vagrant installed. Using the hashicorp/precise32 box, I get this error when running vagrant up in console:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise32'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/Users/staffanestberg/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise32/1.0.0/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "precise32_1406521581335_85787", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "9", "--disk", "/Users/staffanestberg/VirtualBox VMs/precise32_1406521581335_85787/box-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /Users/staffanestberg/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise32/1.0.0/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the imported medium '/Users/staffanestberg/VirtualBox VMs/precise32_1406521581335_85787/box-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: Compressed image is corrupted '/Users/staffanestberg/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise32/1.0.0/virtualbox/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_ZIP_CORRUPTED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Appliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 779 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

OSX 10.9.4 and Vagrant 1.6.3. I saw some threads regarding a similar error which suggested restarting VirtualBox but that didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Your compressed image is corrupt. Try recreating it.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this error (VERR_ZIP_CORRUPTED), deleting the old folders

```
C:\Users\admin\.vagrant.d\boxes\ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64
```

And

```
F:\Maquinas Virtuales\VagrantDemo_default_1456853777482_45208
```

... (Where the virtualbox tried to create the virtual machine)

And then closing all the application that consume ports, like Dropbox, Skype, torrent, firewall,
and then I run again 2 more times (every time deleting the old folder) and it works perfectly.